# Http response Content-Type is json. Error for "Invalid mime type"

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am consuming a 3rd party API for some purpose.

This API responses with a URL, which basically is an Amazon AWS url, which actually has the data I am interested in.

I am able to call the AWS URL via browser and Postman, which responds with data.

But through code, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "json": does not contain '/'
```

I am using Spring Boot and to make http calss, I'm using `RestTemplate`.

Response header:

```
accept-ranges →bytes
content-length →1428
content-type →json
date →Thu, 25 Oct 2018 10:05:57 GMT
last-modified →Wed, 24 Oct 2018 18:44:44 GMT
server →AmazonS3
```

The Content-Type is **"json"**

Code I've used:

```
protected HttpHeaders httpHeader(String encodedApiKey) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", " */*");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, " */*");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

    if (encodedApiKey != null && !encodedApiKey.isEmpty()) {
      headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedApiKey);
    }
    return headers;
  }

  private HttpEntity<Tickets> getHttpEntity(String apiKey) {
    if (apiKey== null || apiKey.isEmpty()) {
      return new HttpEntity<>(httpHeader(null));
    }
    return new HttpEntity<>(httpHeader(encodeBase64(apiKey)));
  }

 ResponseEntity<Tickets> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(awsUri,
 HttpMethod.GET,
 httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Tickets>() {});
}
```

This is giving an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "json": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:534)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:869)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:662)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:339)
```

1. What is it that I'm doing wrong ?
2. I've tried using `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, but this won't modify the server's **response header** (or **Content-Type to *application/json***)

Does anyone has any idea ?

Comment: I think you should use `application/json` in your request at client side. best way use postman to send request.

Comment: Try to send request with this header: `headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);`

Comment: @PandeyAmit Done that. Does not work.

Comment: @Freemahn Does not work. Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check this case by my own but it is extremally similar to you case. Since in the error stack `HttpMessageConverterExtractor` is present I can make an assumption that Spring doesn't know how to convert a response. So you can add a propert `MessageConverter` by yourself:

```
protected HttpHeaders httpHeader(String encodedApiKey) {
 /***/
 restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
 ResponseEntity<Tickets> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(awsUri,
 HttpMethod.GET,
 httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Tickets>() {}); 
}

private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = 
      new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return converters;
}
```

[Here is a full explanation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

**UPD** ResponseExctractor example

```
private class TicketsResponseExtractor extends HttpMessageConverterExtractor<Tickets> {

    public TicketsResponseExtractor (Class<Tickets> responseType,
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        super(responseType, messageConverters);
    }

    @Override
    public Tickets extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            response.getHeaders().set("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            return super.extractData(response);             
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and `RestTemplate` call:

```
ResponseExtractor<Tickets> responseExtractor =
    new TicketsResponseExtractor(Tickets.class, restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
Tickets result =
    restTemplate.execute(awsUri, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseExtractor);
```

Comment: I've tried this along with interceptor. It is not working for me. Is it even possible to modify a server's response header ? (or a particular field in response header)

Comment: hmm. then did you try a custom `ResponseExtractor`?

Comment: I have not yet. Does spring allow to extend/implement any class where we can provide custom impl ?

Comment: How would this work or solve the issue ? I still am getting the same issue and while debugging it still gives content-type as "json"

Comment: MessageConverter didn't actually converted the response's header field for Content-Type. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes you're right - it wont change a header but if the initial aim is to get a response it should help to read a response data despite the incorrect content-type in the header

Comment: Okay I did this:

if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
      response.getHeaders().set("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      return super.extractData(response);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

Is this okay ? cz it is working now !